# Mostrar objeto en un select Angular

Tags: angular

estoy sacando una serie de datos de mi base de datos a través de mi API REST pero cuando quiero pintar los datos no me los muestra sin embargo si le hago un `console.log` a `result` me saca los datos que quiero, el problema es que al hacer un `console.log` de `ots` no me saca nada `undefined` me dice.

Probé creando un modelo y todo lo demás:

```
ots:Array<Ots>

ots:any

ots:string[]

ots = new Array()
```

Todo eso he probado...

Ahora os dejo mi código del TS

```
  getots() {
    this.webData.getots().subscribe(
      result => { 
        if(result["code"] = 200) {
          this.ots = result["data"];
          console.log(result);
          console.log(this.ots);
        } else {
          console.log('Error');
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Y aquí os dejo una captura de la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De pronto probaste pasando los valores de esta forma `this.ots = result;` y así en la vista poder recorrerlos?

Comment: Viendo tu código es como si a tu variable ots estas asignando el valor de result.data, no de result... Si solo es result el data está de mas, y si estas asignando la clave data no lo hagas con corchetes sino usa el punto para entrar a una clave dentro de data: **result.data**

Comment: @jecorrales gracias! no se como no se me ocurrio Y.Y

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín es normal, a todos nos ha pasado. Es con gusto.